# Getting data from SQL Server database

Tags: sql, vb.net

Looking for the simplest way to get a single value from a database. This gets confusing when you consider all of the 9,000 ways that exist to do this in a .NET language. SqlCommands, DataReaders, Recordsets... oh my!

Assume I already have a connection to the DB opened. I simply want to do something like this:

```
Dim age As Integer = <SQL statement here>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string goes here");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT foo FROM ...", conn);

conn.Open();
int age = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
conn.Close();
```

Not a VB.Net guy, but I think it would look something like this in VB.Net:

```
Dim conn As SqlConnection = new SqlConnection("connection string goes here")
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT foo FROM ...", conn);

conn.Open()
Dim age As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
conn.Close()
```

Comment: HAHA! It's hard for a C# guy not too use semi-colons! :D

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
Dim age As Integer=0
Using conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("YourConnectionString") 
    Using cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand() 

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Age FROM Customer WHERE CustomerNumber = @CustNum" 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustNum", SomeCustomerNumber) 
        conn.Open() 
        age = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()) 

      End Using 
End Using
```